# Why Hazelcast has fixed delay (60 seconds) for cleanup cache at CleanupService.registerCache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hazelcast, second-level-cache

I turned on the second level cache (using Hazelcast implementation) and set:

```
<map name="default">
   <time-to-live-seconds>10</time-to-live-seconds>
   <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
</map>
```

Then, I saved the entity using `session.save(entity)`. Then I removed the entity from DB manually and checked if entity is existing in the cache. It still exists and is ok. Then I did wait for 20 seconds and invoked the method to get the entity `session.get(entity.id)` and it returned the entity. I am confused, because I've set `time-to-live-seconds` to 10 seconds and expected the Session to return a null object.

I looked at [src](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate4/3.5.1/com/hazelcast/hibernate/local/CleanupService.java?av=f) :

```
private static final long FIXED_DELAY = 60;
private static final long FIXED_DELAY1 = 60;

public void More ...registerCache(final LocalRegionCache cache) {
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void More ...run() {
                cache.cleanup();
            }
}, FIXED_DELAY, FIXED_DELAY1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Question: Why hazelcast has fixed delay for cleanup cache?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast `LocalCacheRegionFactory` does not use distributed maps instead it work with local caches and does the cache invalidation via ITopic. You can see the detailed architecture from the docs :
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcastlocalcacheregionfactory

The eviction of local caches are according to default cache timeout value which is 1 hour or ttl value of default hazelcast map which is 10 seconds in your case. However the eviction sampling is done with a fixed interval as you said which is 60 seconds and it is not configurable. Since LocalRegionCache does not use hazelcast's own IMap you need to wait the initial 60 seconds for the first sampling.(Code for sampling is done [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.6/hazelcast-hibernate/hazelcast-hibernate3/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/hibernate/local/LocalRegionCache.java#L313))

However, if you use HazelcastCacheRegionFactory which uses IMap you can configure ttl for each entity region. Let's say you have entity called `com.hazelcast.hibernate.entity.DummyEntity` and if you configure IMap map which stores this entity's region cache like this :

```
<map name="com.hazelcast.hibernate.entity.DummyEntity">
   <time-to-live-seconds>10</time-to-live-seconds>
   <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
</map>
```

You should be able to use ttl impl for the IMap.

Also for the `LocalCacheRegionFactory` case, it is a good idea to make fixed delay configurable by the user. You can create an [issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/issues/new) under hazelcast hibernate repo.

Comment: Thank you for reply. For Hazelcast CacheRegionFactory you are right, because HZ uses it own Map. But LocalRegionCache has confused me, because I was expected to see setted behaviour.

Comment: As I said, it uses your setted value but it does not behave as expected, because of fixed value and current behaviour is not well documented. You always create an issue or send a pull request. Right now, this is the current behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. I will create an issue. May be HZ developers don't see the reason make it configurable, because for cache  not a big deal, 60 seconds or 10. BTW what if I set eviction-policy to LRU and eviction-percentage to 50% and my map filled faster then 60 seconds period? Do I get OutOfMemoryException ?

Comment: Eviction rate is also is fixed for LocalRegionCache(https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/blob/master/hazelcast-hibernate3/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/hibernate/local/LocalRegionCache.java#L56) which is 20 percent and you setting eviction policy has no effect because LocalRegionCache uses its own eviction algorithm (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/blob/master/hazelcast-hibernate3/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/hibernate/local/LocalRegionCache.java#L364). You might get OutOfMemoryException if 60 seconds interval is not enough.